# Как убрать пустое пространство под сложной формой?

Tags: css

Есть сложная форма обратной свзи где все элементы выстраиваются при помощи css, все элементы идентичны пример <div class="porguz_1"> блок к примеру с texarea </div>
пример css

```
.porguz_1 {
display: block;
position: relative;
z-index: 99992;
left:0px;
top:-310px;
}
```

и когда все элементы выстроены нужным образом, под всей формой замечаю огромное количество пустого места, которое прокручивается до конца страницы сайта.

В чём я не так пишу стили, почему появляется это пустое место? Подразумеваю что место от первоночального расположения элемента на странице, но я ведь его разместил при помощи css, почему оно осталось?

Comment: firebug наше всё

Comment: Разместите Ваш код на jsfiddle.net, тогда разговор будет боллее конструктивный.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Вы используете position: relative и top: -310px. 
Вы смещаете объекты на 310px вверх относительно нормального (position: static) положения, однако пространство которые они занимают первоначально никуда не девается.

Могу поспорить, что у Вас снизу остаётся 310px пустого пространства?

Comment: Да, всё верно, остаётся место. Когда много элементов у формы их нужно выстроить красиво, то отображается очень много свободного места. Решил это может быть не правельно, но решил. Скажите, может я не так сделал? Вот пример css( это несколько элементов идущих друг под другом
.stoimost_jel_1 {
 display: block;
 position: inherit;
 z-index: 99992;
 left:390px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
}
.stoimost_jel_2 {
 display: block;
 position: inherit;
 z-index: 99992;
 left:390px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
}

Comment: Выложите код на http://jsfiddle.net/ и я Вам помогу, а то по обрывкам css нет возможности чётко сформировать картинку происходящего.

Answer (score 0):

Убрать пространство оставленное после смещение можно так:

```
.porguz_1 {
display: block;
position: relative;
z-index: 99992;
left:0px;
top:-310px;
// добавляем
margin-bottom: -310px
}
```

или использовать такой сдвиг:

```
.porguz_1 {
display: block;
position: relative;
z-index: 99992;
left:0px;
// вместо top:-310px;
margin-top:-310px;
}
```